# Refector-Rename ASP.Net Controls

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there any way to Rename `ASP.Net` Controls without searching the complete Markup or Codebehind.

In `Visual Studio` there is Refactor Rename but this only works in Codebehind I still have to search the Markup code.

I'm using `VS 2008`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've found that the easiest way to do this is from the code behind.

There exists a shortcut called [**Rename Refactoring**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx) that is bound to the keyboard combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). The combination is listed as "Refactor.Rename" in the keyboard settings, if you want to change the shortcut (or if it's not bound, for some reason, you can set it yourself.)

To rename your ASP.NET control, navigate in the aspx.vb file to a reference of the control. Put your mouse cursor on the variable name. Press the keyboard shortcut. Now, you can either start typing (will erase the previous name and start typing a new name), or click somewhere or use the arrow keys to navigate to a specific position in the variable, after which you can add/remove/change the name as you please.

Clicking elsewhere will not apply the changes. To apply the operation, either click "Apply" in the dialog at the top-right that appeared, or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**The ASP control will be renamed in the VB code, and in the aspx code!**

*Note that there are certain file types where Refactor.Rename is "not available", such as .ashx or Visual C++ files.*